# React rails authentication - Get user state without page reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm building a SPA with rails API on the back-end and React on the front-end. The user authentication works as desired and I'm getting the user state from the rails. The problem is that when a user signs in to the app, I have to manually refresh the whole browser to update the state.

```js
// App.js

function userReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "success": {
      return {
        ...state,
        id: action.id,
        username: action.username,
        email: action.email,
        logged_in: action.status,
        error: ""
      };
    }
    case "fail": {
      return {
        ...state,
        id: "",
        username: "",
        email: "",
        logged_in: false,
        error: action.error
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
// set initial state of the logged in user
const intialUserState = {
  id: "",
  username: "",
  email: "",
  logged_in: false,
  error: ""
};

export const UserStatus = React.createContext(intialUserState);

function App() {
  const [userState, dispatch] = useReducer(userReducer, intialUserState);

  // fetch the user's data
  function fetchLoggedInUserData() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/logged_in", { withCredential: true })
      .then(response => {
        const { id, username, email, logged_in } = response.data;
        if (response.status === 200) {
          dispatch({
            type: "success",
            id: id,
            username: username,
            email: email,
            status: logged_in
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch({ type: "fail", error: error });
      });
  }

  // when the app loads, check if the user is signed in or not.
  // if the user is signed in, then store the user's data into the state
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchLoggedInUserData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <UserStatus.Provider value={{ userState, dispatch }}>
      <Router>
        <>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
            <Route path="/" render={props => <Public {...props} />} />
          </Switch>
        </>
      </Router>
    </UserStatus.Provider>
  );
}
```

The above code works as expected and I can store the user state as you see from the code. The problem is when a user clicks on the submit button I want to automatically store the user without having to refresh the page. The code below is from `Login.js`

```js
// Login.js

function signinReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "field": {
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.field]: action.value
      };
    }
    case "signin": {
      return {
        ...state,
        error: "",
        isLoading: true
      };
    }
    case "success": {
      return {
        ...state,
        error: "",
        isLoading: false
      };
    }
    case "error": {
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        error: action.error
      };
    }
  }
}

const initialState = {
  username: "",
  password: "",
  isLoading: false,
  error: ""
};

function FormMain() {
  const [signinState, dispatch] = useReducer(signinReducer, initialState);

  const { username, password, isLoading, error } = signinState;

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({ type: "signin" });
    await postUserData();
  };

  function postUserData() {
    axios
      .post(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions",
        {
          user: {
            username: username,
            password: password
          }
        },
        { withCredentials: true }
      )
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          dispatch({ type: "success" });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // dispatch({ type: "error", error: error.response.data[0] });
      });
  }
}
```

I have removed the sign-in form from the code above as it was getting too lengthy. 
The solution can be to somehow transfer the state from the `Login.js` to `App.js` or directly update the state of the `App.js` from the `Login.js` and make use of the `useEffect` in the `App.js`, and update the state without having to manually refresh the browser but I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed by creating a new `case` to `App.js` and updating that `case` from `Login.js`.

```js
// App.js

function userReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "success": {
      return {
        ...state,
        id: action.id,
        username: action.username,
        email: action.email,
        admin: action.admin,
        logged_in: action.status,
        error: ""
      };
    }
    case "fail": {
      return {
        ...state,
        id: "",
        username: "",
        email: "",
        admin: false,
        logged_in: false,
        error: action.error
      };
    }
    case "globalFetch": {
      return {
        ...state,
        id: action.id,
        username: action.username,
        email: action.email,
        admin: action.admin,
        logged_in: action.status,
        error: ""
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

As you can see the `globalFetch` case can be easily passed down to the `Login.js` via useContext and then update the case as per your requirement.

```js
// Login.js

function postUserData() {
    axios
      .post(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions",
        {
          user: {
            username: username,
            password: password
          }
        },
        { withCredentials: true }
      )
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          const { id, username, email, logged_in, admin } = response.data;
          dispatch({ type: "success" });
          state.dispatch({
            type: "globalFetch",
            id: id,
            username: username,
            email: email,
            admin: admin,
            status: logged_in
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // dispatch({ type: "error", error: error.response.data[0] });
      });
  }
 // More code...
}
```

Comment: If anyone has a better solution feel free to answer.